# ResponseException in jaunt

Tags: exception, web-scraping, jaunt-api

**Here is the error** 
message: UserAgent.sendGET; response error

requestUrl: https://www.linkedin.com/directory/topics-c/

response: 
  requestURL: https://www.linkedin.com/directory/topics-c/

status: 999

**here is my code**

try {
            Document doc = userAgent.visit(link);

```
        Elements eles = doc.findEvery("<ul class=\"column quad-column\">");
        for (int i = 0; i < eles.size(); i++) {
            Elements href_keywords = eles.getElement(i).findEvery("<a href>");
            for (int j = 0; j < href_keywords.size(); j++) {
                keywords.add(href_keywords.getElement(j).getText());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should find the elements like this:

Elements eles = userAgent.doc.findEvery("");

here is the full code:

```
package scrap;

import com.jaunt.*;

public class Scrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent();
            userAgent.visit("https://www.linkedin.com/directory/topics-c/");
       //     System.out.println(userAgent.doc.innerHTML());
            Elements eles = userAgent.doc.findEvery("<ul class=\"column quad-column\">");
            for (int i = 0; i < eles.size(); i++) {
                Elements href_keywords = eles.getElement(i).findEvery("<a href>");
                for (int j = 0; j < href_keywords.size(); j++) {

                    /// here add to your LIST
                    System.out.println(href_keywords.getElement(j).getText()); 
                }
            }
        } catch (JauntException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry if i couldnt see the difference but this is what i have done in my code.

Comment: Could you try to run the code with the latest jaunt and put the complete mistake and all your code?

because I run the code in the response since eh and I get as a result:  " "Customer Service" 
"Customer Satisfaction"